# ios sdk only one view changes at a time bug

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm pushing a number of views:

- the top one is a UITabBarController
- the second one is a UINavigationController with a pushed view
- the third one is a modal box.

Once the close button in the modalbox is pressed I'm trying to revert everything to the default state and change the tabbar index.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];     
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

This dismisses the modal view but doesn't do anything else. Any ideas what could be wrong? I read something about a possible ios bug but I don't know how to work around it.

Comment: First: UITabBarController and UINavigationController aren't views. Second: Where do you call all those methods?

Comment: Where does this snippet live? For example, if it's in the `modalViewController`, then the second two make no sense once that view is dismissed.

Comment: @dasdom: I'm calling them at the bottom of the stack, in the modal ViewController.

Comment: @pengone: Can you elaborate? I don't understand. Both tabBarController and navigationController are available and can be used.

Comment: The modal ViewController has no navigationController and does not know about a tabBarController!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither [`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) nor [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a view. Both are subclasses of `UIViewController` and have a property `NSArray *viewControllers`.

If you have an `actualView` controlled by an `ActualViewController` that is pushed on top of a `rootView` controlled by a `RootViewController` that is the `rootViewController` for the `navigationController`, and you also have a `modalView` controlled by a `ModalViewController`, then put

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in `ModalViewController.m`, and put

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

in `ActualViewController.m` (from whence `modalView` is pushed, presumably), and put

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

in `RootViewController.m` (from whence `actualView` is pushed, presumably).

If `modalViewController` was never added to the `navigationController`, then it doesn't know that the `navigationController` exists.

If `actualViewController` was never added to the `tabBarController`, then it doesn't know that the `tabBarController` exists.

Answer (score 0):

The easy (and dirty) way:
Dismiss the modal view in the modal view. Make the navigation view controller the delegate of the modal view. Make the tabbar controller the delegate of the navigation controller. When the button is pressed call a method in the navigation controller that pops the view and calls a method of the tabbar controller which changes the selected tab.